American English: (1) Thank you for all you did for me. (2) Thank you for all have done for me
I have a good friend. She always helps me whenever I get into trouble. We are still friend now. I just want to express my gratitude.
Me: You are so kind. You always help me whenever I get into trouble. Thank you for all you did/ have done for me. I'm so grateful to have such a good friend as you.
My friend. Don't overthink it. I am happy when I see you are happy.
Can I use either? What is the difference between these 2 sentences?

(1) Thank you for all you did for me. I am so grateful and lucky to have a friend like you.
(2) Thank you for all you have done for me.I am so grateful and lucky to have a friend like you.

I know that in BrE, only (2) with present perfect is acceptable. I wondering if in the US, if (1) with the simple past is correct to use in this context.

There's no significant US/UK usage split here. Since the current "temporal focus" is now, time of speaking (speaker is currently thanking someone) it's more natural to use Present Perfect rather than "Simple Past with do-support". But you're wrong to say "in BrE, only (2) with present perfect is acceptable" - it's just a preference, not a "rule".

If you want to improve your English, devote more attention to avoiding mistakes in She always helps me whenever I have trouble. We are still friends now. Note that help and friend are very noticeable errors there, but no-one would particularly notice or care which of (1) or (2) you used.

@FumbleFingers So you seriously think the OP will understand your first comment? It's not a preference only. It depends on what you mean and want to say.

@Lambie sometimes, the opinions from native speakers are not the same, this often make me confused. But I am still feel grateful with all natives who help here.

@Lambie: I don't see the point of your comment. Almost every English utterance can have a huge range of meanings given sufficiently contrived contexts, so your point about "It depends on what you mean and want to say" is largely irrelevant. My two points were that (1) there's no significant US/UK usage split, and (2) the verb form is almost always just a preference, not a "rule". Sure - if the speaker is thanking someone for things done many decades ago, since which time they've had no further interaction, #2 is very unlikely. But that's contrived, and it's still only "preference".

@FumbleFingers I prefer chocolate cake to vanilla cake. But when I thank someone, it's not preference, it's intended meaning. Learners need to understand the difference. Because if you say it's preference, you ignore the difference in meaning. If you stay with a friend over the weekend, maybe they did only one thing for which you are thanking them. OR maybe they did more than one thing. So, there's a difference, not a preference.

@LE123 Even doctors differ in their advice. Based on my personal experience take a second opinion if you doubt. OR follow a doctor's advice you trust. Reference: "the opinions from native speakers are not the same, this often make me confused". Sometimes it may be due to regional dialect. I find that we mostly follow British English (Fumble Fingers). So instead of getting confused, Do in Rome as Romans do.

@JamesMathai The expression is: When in Rome do as the Romans do.


Thank you for all you have done for me.
or
Thank you for everything you have done for me.

would probably be the most common thing to say. I don't think there's a split between American and British English.

Is it in correct to use “you did” - simple past in this context?

If the speaker is thanking someone for things done many decades ago, since which time there's been no further interaction, he'd be much more likely to use simple past format #1. But that's effectively a contrived context. In most common contexts it would be better to use Present Perfect. And just because one phrasing is (stylistically) "better" than another doesn't mean the alternative is somehow "incorrect".

This answer does not address the issue.

(1) Thank you for all you did for me. [in the past, the doing is over. last week or last month or even this morning, for example]. The person may have only done one thing for you. There, use did.
What did I do for you? I wrote you a letter of recommendation.
(2) Thank you for all have done for me. [in the past we don't know when and it's true up until now in the present moment of speaking. It signals the past, it does not imply or say when in the past] It also implies that more than one thing was done for you.
What did I do for you? I washed and ironed your clothes, I repaired your car and I helped you finish writing a paper. Use: Have done because we don't know when these things occurred, only that they are in the past. And what is important is not when they occurred, only that there was help up to the time of speaking and that it occurred in the past.
There is no AmE/BrE difference here.

In the context I provided in the original post, there is no specific past time and no implied specific past time . So using the simple past here is wrong. Right?

It seems that the context refers to all the helps from the past until now

@LE123 No, it is not wrong. This question is just like the other one you asked. It works the same exact way. You are not getting it. The "did" means the speaker sees it as over and finished. You do not need to mention a specific or implied past time. The simple past tense implies it even if not stated. That's the whole point of using it.

Since we first met each other (maybe 10 year ago) until now, my friend have always helped me.  She helps me regularly, verytime I need support. Now, she still is willing to help me in life. I want to say a sentence to express my gratetude and how lucky I am to have a friend like her. Is the simple past still correct here : (2) Thank you for all you did for me. I am so grateful and lucky to have a friend like you.

@LE123 It's your choice. If her helping you is finished, simple past; if it is relevant to the present day, use the present perfect.// [I'm so tired of spending so much time explaining things like this and then getting no votes at all when the other answer doesn't even answer the question. It's unbelievable.]
