(1) We never spoke until today. (2) We have never spoken until today
SEE THE CLIP HERE
Context: (In the clip) This morning, After a long time they haven't seen, the mother met a man who was her boy friend in the past. Now, in the evening,the mother talk with the daughter:
The character said:
(1) We never spoke until today.
How about this sentence:
(2) We have never spoken until today.
Can I use (2) instead?
What is the difference between (1) and (2) in this context?

(1) American (2) British.

if so in this link https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/359346/american-english-1-thank-you-for-all-you-did-for-me-2-thank-you-for-all-ha/359351#359351 (1) Thank you for all you did for me.=> American//////
(2) Thank you for all have done for me.=> British. Right? Because that As I see, the contexts are the same. Two contexts refer to a period of time until the present.

"After a long time they haven't seen". What is that?

I meant “after a long time they haven’t meet each other “

So, that would be: they haven't seen each other or met for a long time.

It's part of the story she is telling about the past. "We never saw each other again. We never even spoke until today." To say "We have never spoken" would be equally valid as a sentence, but doesn't fit so well in this context.

I do not know who is downvoting my answer but they are mistaken.

(1) We never spoke until today.
There was no single occasion when we spoke until today. We spoke earlier in the day, this morning, for example.
(2) We have never spoken until today.
That merely signals the past, we don't know when, up to the moment of speaking. It means up and until this moment of speaking NOW, we had not spoken.
This use of the present perfect that signals the past without specificity regarding when something occurs is the most difficult one for learners to assimilate.

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/359346/american-english-1-thank-you-for-all-you-did-for-me-2-thank-you-for-all-ha/359351#359351 If so, in this link, I can use simple past (you did) to refer to every single occasion. Right?

@LE123 The simple past is in the past, over and finished. Somebody did something for someone in the past.  So, thank you for everything you did for me (at some particular time: last week, during the holiday, last year). Last week is finished so is your doing something for me. Make an effort to feel the difference between the two. Doesn't your language have a simple past? Because then all you have to do is understand the present perfect...

@LE123 I have given you the explanation. I think others may not have actually taught English.
